# Quick general purpose linked list in C

Tags: c, linked-list, memory-management

I want to use it when some function needs to return a list of something. Is it working as I think it should or is there undefined behavior somewhere? What I really tried to achieve is something like a templated `<list>` from C++ - for any type. I'm not sure if there is a standard solution/include/library for this.

list.h

```
#pragma once

#include <stddef.h>

struct list_handler
{
    struct list_node *head;
    struct list_node *tail;
    size_t count;
};

struct list_node
{
    void *data;
    struct list_node *next;
};

void list_init(struct list_handler *list);
void list_add(struct list_handler *list, void *data);
void list_free(struct list_handler *list);
void list_foreach(struct list_handler *list, void (*foreach_function)(void *));
```

list.c

```
#include "list.h"

#include <stdlib.h>

void list_init(struct list_handler *list)
{
    list->head = NULL;
    list->tail = NULL;
    list->count = 0;
}

void list_add(struct list_handler *list, void *data)
{
    struct list_node *new_node = malloc(sizeof(struct list_node));

    new_node->data = data;
    new_node->next = NULL;

    if (list->count > 0)
    {
        list->tail->next = new_node;
    }
    else
    {
        list->head = new_node;
    }

    list->tail = new_node;

    ++list->count;
}

void list_free(struct list_handler *list)
{
    struct list_node *current = list->head;
    struct list_node *previous;

    while (current != NULL)
    {
        previous = current;
        current = current->next;

        free(current);

        list->head = current;
        --list->count;
    }

    list->tail = NULL;
}

void list_foreach(struct list_handler *list, void (*foreach_function)(void *))
{
    struct list_node *current = list->head;

    while (current != NULL)
    {
        (*foreach_function)(current->data);
        current = current->next;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
void list_print(void *data)
{
    int *temp = (int*) data;
    printf("%d\n", *temp);
}

void list_free_data(void *data)
{
    int *temp = (int*) data;
    free(temp);
    data = NULL;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    struct list_handler list;
    list_init(&list);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
    {
        int *data = malloc(sizeof(int));
        *data = i;
        list_add(&list, data);
    }

    list_foreach(&list, list_print);
    list_foreach(&list, list_free_data);

    list_free(&list);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The only direct question is "Is it working as I think it should or is there undefined behavior somewhere?".  Posts here should include "working" code, so please state another review goal than that.

Comment: Is the "quick" in the title referring to runtime speed, or ease of development, or something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. "What I really tried to achieve is something like a templated `<list>` from C++ - for any type." Approach has limited applicability in that it only well handles pointers to object types, not *any* type.   Still, this limited use is sufficient for many applications.
2. `size_t count` member is unnecessary with current function interface as only its zero-ness is tested and that may be determined by other simple code.
3. Advanced: With current function interface, keeping track of both `head` and `tail` is not needed.  A tail pointer is sufficient.  Let the tail point to the head of the list rather than `NULL`.  Now `struct list_handler` can be a simple pointer instead.  `list_init();` could be replaced with `struct list_handler *list = NULL;`
4. Definition of `struct list_node` is not needed in `list.h`.  Move to `list.c` to simplify user's view of this `list_...` code.
5. Like mentioned by [@Joop Eggen](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/13680/joop-eggen), `list_foreach` should have a state variable.  Also having a return value that stops the loop when non-zero is *very* useful.  Maybe an `int` or a pointer to `data`.  Consider using this to perform a search.

   ```
   int list_foreach(struct list_handler *list, 
       int (*foreach_function)(void *state, void *data), void *state) {
     struct list_node *current = list->head;
     while (current != NULL) {
       int i = (*foreach_function)(state, current->data);
       if (i) {
         return i;
       } 
       current = current->next;
     }
     return 0;
   }
   ```
6. Like `free()` accepts `free(NULL)`, `list_free()` should also tolerate `list_free(NULL)`.

Answer (score 2):

The list_free has a small error.
Whether the function should free the list is up to the API design. Maybe you did not want dangling pointers. Then the name should be better `list_clear`.

```
void list_free(struct list_handler *list)
{
    struct list_node *current = list->head;
    struct list_node *previous;

    while (current != NULL)
    {
        previous = current;
        current = current->next;

        //- free(current);
        free(previous); //+

        list->head = current;
        --list->count;
    }

    list->tail = NULL;
    free(list); //+
}
```

Freeing the data is a non-list issue, misleading, especially with a `void*`.

```
void list_free_data(void *data)
{
    //int *temp = (int*) data;
    //free(temp);
    //data = NULL;
    free(data);
}
```

Assigning NULL to data has no effect.

However if you want to free the list *with* freeing the data:

```
list_foreach(list, free);
list_free(list);
free(list);
```

The `list_foreach` is limited as it must work with side-effects, storing results or other context in global variables. Better provide a for-each with an additional parameter. So bad coding style is not inevitable.

For the remainder: I like APIs to provide a full set of operations, that is with a `remove` too.

Comment: First of all, thanks for the bug fix with `free(current)` to `free(previous)` - totally overlooked this.
I have several questions about `list_free_data` fixes:
1) Is it safe to free a `void*` pointer in `list_free_data`? As far as I know, `free` has no way of knowing the size of the underlying object if a pointer is a `void*`. This is why I created `list_free_data` instead of passing `free` from `stdlib.h` directly - to handle the type.
2) [About assigning NULL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1025604/2042546) - that way I signal to a higher level that the memory has been freed.

Comment: Memory allocation has its own administration of sizes. Hence `void*` is fine, and NULL does not need to be assigned, other than prevent the usage of freed pointers ("dangling pointers"). Note: `free` of `char*` would not free one char, but could be done on an array. For concepts C is not that pedagogical, as opposed to Pascal/Modula-2.